# Creating level codes with action script 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2

I want to create level codes, like in sea of fire (http://armorgames.com/play/351/sea-of-fire)
I have a text input box with the instance name "code" and a button that has this code:

```
on (release) {
if (code = 96925) {
gotoAndStop(4);
}
if (code = 34468) {
gotoAndStop(5);
}
if (code = 57575) {
gotoAndStop(6);
}
if (code = 86242) {
gotoAndStop(7);
}
if (code = 99457) {
gotoAndStop(8);
}
if (code = 66988) {
gotoAndStop(10);
}
if (code = !96925 && !34468 && !57575 && !86242 && !99457 && !66988) {
gotoAndStop(3);
}
}
```

I've tried to use code.text instead of just code, I've also tried quotes around the numbers, also I tried both together but it always sends you to frame 10 even if the code is invalid.

Comment: what on earth is !96925. a constant false? you really need to learn some basics of the actionscript syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditional operator (==), not equality operator (=) in 'if' condition
Also if 'code' is a text field then you need to use code.text
You can put trace to check for the value of code.
I do not understand your last if condition

Instead you can use if - else if - else here.